# Is it possible to create a new BigCommerce page template without installing Stencil locally?

Tags: templates, bigcommerce

I am not a coder, by any means, but I am confident in my ability to make HTML, CSS, and some PHP alterations to existing websites. I want to create a new page template for a client's BigCommerce storefront so the layout is specific to a content type; so far my attempts of uploading this template have not been successful and I am wondering if I am missing something.

Details:

- I have not created a local installation of Stencil. I hope to just create the template and make changes via the online Theme Editor.
- I have downloaded the theme from BigCommerce; my new page has been created from the default page.html file and then placed in the following path: templates/pages/custom/page/custom_page.html.
- I have deleted the manifest.json file.
- I compress the entire theme folder (zip) and try uploading it via My Themes.
- I went into the config.json file and changed the theme name from the original.
- I get the following error when trying to upload the theme: "There was a problem processing your theme".

So - what am I doing wrong? I assume it is a lot of things. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to be a bit more clear. Can you show us the minimum amount of code required to replicate the problem?

Comment: Using the page.html file as your starting point will not give you your expected results. You want to work off one of the partials/templates that best fits the page you are trying to create. Also, I don't think the download and upload features are meant to be used like this, although I cannot verify as I've never tried. My advice - get stencil running locally, or hire a developer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot show you the minimum amount of code to replicate the problem because "code" is not the issue (at least, that is my understanding). As mentioned in my original post, I have followed BigCommerce's  instructions on the subdirectory structure of the page templates (see here: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/authoring-custom-templates). I have laid out what I am trying to accomplish and the steps I've made thus far to get me where I am at this moment.

Comment: Additional note: Most of the actions I've made up to this point has been through research of different posts on Stack Overflow or BigCommerce help articles. I wouldn't be reaching out for help if I didn't already try finding the solution on my own.

Comment: @tim-diztinct - re: download/upload, I was thinking the same thing, but in the following article it says that it can be done: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Custom-Theme-Upload. But, to your point, I don't think I can easily just create a new page template file without installing Stencil locally.

Comment: Reading the first line of the 'Custom Theme Upload' article you linked. "Making customizations to Stencil themes requires the use of the Stencil CLI framework." Why not work in BC's suggested workflow?

Comment: @tim-diztinct - The customization(s) I am trying to make are pretty minor; I was trying to avoid having to install Stencil locally for minor coding, especially if I can use the online Theme Editor to make those quick customizations. Plus, the customization is for a non-functioning part of the website. Unless anyone else can offer some advice, it looks like installing the framework is the only path to take.

Comment: Overdue update - my client required specific changes to the website that required local development, which I finally did and everything is working swimmingly. Thank you for your help!